# How to use proguard after making app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk, proguard

I have made my Android app, & for minimizing the apk size, I want to use proguard. 
I am using these 4 libraries in my project

1. easyfacebookandroidsdk_2.3.jar
2. android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
3. google-play-services.jar
4. android-support-v4.jar

Mainifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
   android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="COI: Ministry of Law &amp; Justice"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"    
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution.ShareActivity"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"></activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Currently there is no code in my `project.properties.txt`. Please tell me what should I code in `project.properties.txt` to that the size of my app will be minimized ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what do u build with ? ant / gradle / eclipse

Comment: @RobertRowntree I am using eclipse (perhaps with ant) !

Comment: proguard will keep empty spaces and commented text in code,it could be  reduce the memory while executing the app

Answer (score 0):

With eclipse i dont think you have to do anything special for the 4 jars you mention that will be locate in the ./libs folder and should get handled automatic by eclipse build.

I dont think with this specific list that you need to alter 'project.properties' in any way.

In proguard config you need the std. treatment for jars, external interfaces...

```
-keep        class android.support.v13.** { *; }
-keep        class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep        class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-libraryjars ...
```

Comment: Do I have to replace * with something else ?

Comment: your last line of code means that this code should I add in the last ?
 
    `-easyfacebookandroidsdk_2.3.jar`

    `-android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`

    `-google-play-services.jar`
    `-android-support-v4.jar`

Comment: Also what is v13 ? Why v13 ?

Comment: Do I have to downaload a particular software of proguard

Comment: those are general examples dealing with support libs. Read the proguard docs so you have some understand of what is involved.